# Update table in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have two tables:

```
stock (ItemName,Quantity)
```

and

```
 WeeklyStock (ItemName,StartQuantity,EndQuantity,date).
```

I want update `WeeklyStock` table at start and end of the week when system date is changed.

Should I use trigger? If yes then how? .

Comment: And vote for the helpful ones. You run the risk of alienating yourself from the community and from recieving any further help.

Answer (score 4):

No, you shouldn't use a trigger to perform a weekly job.

Use [SQLServerAgent Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153.aspx) or perhaps a [maintenance task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139753.aspx). Alternatively, perhaps your application could stimulate the activity in some way.

Triggers are used to perform activity in response to a data change, generally to maintain integrity across the schema.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger is fired when you make a change to the data in the database (namely: insert, update or delete). Therefore, this will not be suitable for your purposes.

To fire things off in a periodic fashion in SQL Server your should cerate a scheduled task in the SQL Server Agent that will run your update procedure.